# Is it possible to disable single function keys?

Tags: keyboard

I know through System Preferences I can disable all the function keys. However, I really only need two of the function keys to have different functions. Rather than having to always press 'fn', is there a way to disable just these function keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/)

FunctionFlip can 'flip' certain function keys instead of changing all keys.

> FunctionFlip individually controls your MacBook or MacBook Pro's function keys, turning special keys back to regular F-keys, or vice-versa.

[image: FunctionFlip]

> FunctionFlip's purpose is simply to disable the special features — rewind, play, mute, etc. — on the function keys. For example, if you "flip" F7, F8, and F9, those keys — only those keys — will revert back to normal F keys. Press the fn key with the special key to get the special function back. That is, the "special" and "normal" functions are flipped.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Though if possible I would like not to rely on third party software running in the background. Is there really no way to make a permanent change?